# Unknown configuration option `group_imports` for rustfmt

Tags: rust, formatting, toml, rustfmt

I have a **rustfmt.toml** file with the line `group_imports = "StdExternalCrate"` in it, which according to [the documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=master&search=#group_imports) should be a valid option. However, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Unknown configuration option `group_imports`

Running `rustfmt` on a test file didn't seem to group the imports as specified either. I've updated everything today with `rustup update` and currently have version *"rustfmt 1.4.27-nightly"*, which [seems to be the latest stable minor version](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1424-2020-11-05).

I've also made sure to enable unstable features with `unstable_features = true`, as per documentation. Why can't I use this option? Is it because I'm using nightly? How would I go about enabling this option in that case?

Full rustfmt.toml file for reference:

```
edition = "2018"
unstable_features = true

format_code_in_doc_comments = true

brace_style = "AlwaysNextLine"
control_brace_style = "AlwaysNextLine"

fn_single_line = true
where_single_line = true

blank_lines_upper_bound = 2
inline_attribute_width = 32

reorder_impl_items = true
group_imports = "StdExternalCrate"

enum_discrim_align_threshold = 16
struct_field_align_threshold = 16
```

Comment: Uhm, looks like the [documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=master&search=#group_imports) pointing to master, so I guess you would need version `2.0.0` of rustfmt for using that.

Comment: @Netwave You seem to be correct. Inserting the version number in the link (https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=1.4.27&search=#group_imports) seem to confirm it's not in that version. A bit weird that the documentation and master branch is referencing unreleased code while the pulled crate is on version 1.4.27. And the option doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-unreleased).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option simply wasn't available in the version pulled from the crate. The documentation pointed to a later (at the time) unreleased code. The option is available in version 2.0.0, according to the documentation.